# Touchscreen GUI with control loop

Tags: touchscreen, gui

I'd like to create a fullscreen-GUI on my Pi's 7"-touchscreen and I think this would be pretty easy to accomplish if I just wanna have some GUI that let's me click some buttons to control some GPIO-pins, but I need a control-loop that runs over and over again in the background.

I also want the GUI to react to things that happen in the background-loop, for example when a button is pressed or a digital sensor activates an input.

This may be easy to solve, but I can't find a solution, I'm not that experienced with the raspberry pi, I just worked a lot more with Arduino.

I thought about doing all this with processing, because it's very "arduino-like", but I'd like to achieve this with python and I guess I just don't know how to do it, this can't be that hard.

Comment: I would do some research on frameworks such as tkinter, pygame and kivy

Answer (score 1):

As @Dirk says if you search for Raspberry Pi Python GPIO and tkinter or pygame or kivy you should find lots of examples.

Here is my example using pigpio and Kivy.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_kivy_GPIO_py